# Run jhipster test case individually in STS

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jhipster

I created a spring-boot application using jhipster and open in Spring Studio Tool.

To run Junit cases when I click on any Test File and Run as JUnit, it shows  `DEBUG : [onnection adder] org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL               : converting regular socket connection to ssl` in console window in JUnit shows `Runs 0/0 ,Errors 0, Failures 0` .

How I can run each test case in Jhipster. I write test case like below

```
      @Test
      public void saveApplication() throws Exception {
      restMockMvc.perform(post("/api/application")
                  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                  .content(asJsonString(App)))
                  .andExpect(status().isOk());
      }
```

and junit only shows Run  1/21 , failed 1 when liquibase lock error comes.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question, you say you got a Liquibase lock error on postgresql, are you running postgresql using testcontainers? How is related to STS? Does it work when running from maven command line?

Comment: what's the liquibase lock error that you are getting? post full stacktrace